# How to set anchor tag links for production code?

Tags: html, apache

I am building a html/css/js website. In local code, I have set links as `<a href="about.html">` which opens the corresponding page properly.
I will have to deploy this website on an apache server using a ftp client. The domain is already configured and I wanted to know if the same tags will work properly after deployment or will I have to change them to something like `<a href="mydomain.com/about.html">`?

Comment: @Johannes yes it was a typo

Comment: consider accepting an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5922140/daniel) and [WiatroBosy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14912402/wiatrobosy) said,
If the file you are linking, i.e. about.html, is in the same directory with the file which has the [a tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) (`<a href="about.html">`), the link will work, else it will not work.

But there are more disadvantages, those are:

- Assume that the file that has the [a tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), is index.html, and if the user visits example.com/index.html/ instead of example.com/index.html, i.e if the user visits the page with a slash at the end, it will break the link. Instead of the link going to example.com/about.html, it will go to example.com/index.html/about.html, which will probably result in the same page (index.html), or might result in a 404 error.
- If you use the same for linking stylesheets using the [link tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), the same above problem will occur.

---

### How to solve this?

Use `/path/to/about.html`, I would suggest to never use `about.html`, and only use `domain.com/about.html` when the resource is in a different domain from the one the website is hosted on.

So, your [a tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) would be `<a href="/path/to/about.html">`, or if it is in the root directory use `<a href="/about.html">`

Answer (score 0):

If your index.html and about.html are in the same directory - it will work the same

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep the same folder structure when you upload your project to the server, they will keep working. You don't have to add the domain in front.